# User does not exist in MySQL , c# and asp.NET MVC

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc-2

I am working on development machine without making any user account [i have three of four account who comes when i installed them].

so i open the connection everywhere by a globals variable who hold the connectionstring off-course value of variable can not be changed it's constant.

i open the connection using root account who come by default in mysql server. they work fine everywhere.

but my code try to run a command then server return the error that

```
The user specified as a definer ('admin'@'localhost') does not exist
```

i don't know why i got this error even in debug i found that connection open by root and they work fine everywhere else.

so the problem is why they tell me about admin@localhost even the connection my code open by root.

are their anything my code try to do who need authentication or need admin account even they not have then give me exception.

Are you know that what is gone wrong.

Comment: Hi, is it possible that something has been changed on the server side regarding users or network permissions?

Answer (score 0):

I got this error after DB was moved to another server.
There no such user 'admin' so I got the error.

Solution:
log into mysql as root

```
grant all on *.* to admin@localhost identified by "s!5_superp@ss!";
flush privileges;
```